# Simplest (cheapest) adjustable PWM oscillator?

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, oscillator, 555

I'm trying to make an oscillator where I can adjust the frequency and the duty cycle independently, but I'm not having much luck. What I want is a frequency range from 1Hz to 1MHz; and the ability to adjust the duty cycle in 10% increments from 0% to 100%, give or take. Ideally, I'd also like to be able to specify a 25% or 75% duty cycle.

**My question basically boils down to:** What is the simplest (i.e cheapest and smallest) way to achieve an adjustable square wave oscillator with adjustable duty cycle, with the specifications above, and where adjusting either the frequency or the duty cycle does not cause the other to change?

**Here follows a detailed explanation of how I got here:**

My first thought was a 555 timer, but that was very problematic. Adjusting the duty cycle also had an impact on the frequency, and achieving a duty cycle of less than 50% was pretty much impossible.

[image: 555 timer PWM]

My second attempt involved a schmitt inverter. Sadly, the schmitt zone wasn't centred evenly between VCC and GND, so I had to offset the input voltage using a voltage divider. This then limited the current to the point that the (TTL) schmitt did not function. I later swapped it out for a CMOS variant and removed the resistors, but still couldn't get anywhere near reliable operation.

[image: schmitt inverter PWM]

My third idea was to get a microcontroller - specifically, a PIC12F675 - to use its ADC to read two potentiometers, and from these values generate a square wave programmatically. However, when I crunched the numbers, it turned out to be impractical.

A PIC12F675 has a maximum clock speed of 4MHz. If we assume that it will occasionally have to perform up to 10 instructions between changing output states, and bearing in mind that a full wave requires 2 state changes, we end up with a maximum output frequency of 200KHz. This is somewhat lower than I was looking for.

In addition, at this maximum frequency of 200KHz, the MCU will (by definition) be unable to change state any more quickly; and therefore the duty cycle will be fixed at 50%, defeating the purpose. We we assume that we require at least an adjustable range of 10% - 90%, we will be unable to generate an output frequency of more than approximately 20KHz. Or maybe 10KHz.

Using a faster MCU wouldn't help much. The ATmega328 has a maximum clock frequency of 16MHz, which would give us up to 80KHz output. Still not very useful.

My fourth idea involved two 555 timers - one generating an adjustable square wave with a fixed duty cycle, the other acting as a one-shot to generate the duty cycle. Unfortunately, the duty cycle would be measured in time, rather than percentage, and therefore adjusting the frequency would affect the duty cycle. In addition, at the extreme low or high end of the frequency range, the duty cycle adjustment knob would be totally ineffectual for the majority of its travel.

My fifth idea involved a 555 timer for generating the square wave (as above), with a 4017 decade counter to split the output into chunks. Connecting the first output, for example, would give me a 10% duty cycle. I could change the frequency without affecting the duty cycle. There are some problems with this approach, though.

Firstly, unless I wanted to be flipping jumpers by hand, I would need some way to control the output with a knob. So a microcontroller, then. The microcontroller would need some sort of programmable multi-channel switch, such as the [PCA9548A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/scps143e/scps143e.pdf). Unfortunately this is an 8-channel switch, and I'm using a decade counter. I could connect the 4017 reset to the 8th position, and make it an 8-way counter, but then I wouldn't be able to get 10% or 90% duty cycle. So I'd need quite a lot of parts: 1 capacitor, 1 pot, 1 555 timer, 1 MCU, 1 4017 and 2 8-channel switches.

If I wanted a 25% or 75% duty cycle, I would need to add to this list another 4017, another switch IC, another capacitor and some way to switch the capacitors programmatically.

Comment: Since you're already down the learning curve with PIC12F675, consider using Microchip's Numerically-controlled-oscillator (NCO) versions (example: 16F1507). These are fairly versatile.

Comment: @glen_geek Thank you, I will look into that chip. I notice, however, that it comes in a 20-pin DIP. Do you know of anything similar in a DIP8 form factor? Size is an issue, here. And sadly, SMD is difficult for me at present.

Comment: So, that's a really bad situation. If size matters, don't use DIP. SOIC and the like really aren't hard to solder at all.

Comment: @MarcusMüller They are when you're using matrix board. I'm not convinced I'd have much luck etching my own PCBs precisely enough to mount SMD chips.

Comment: @SodAlmighty I used to do that, it's not that hard, but I've stopped, since making my own boards was harder, less exact and also more expensive in tools and waste then just ordering very small boards from http://oshpark.com or medium-sized boards from elecrow.com. It really is a time-saver, compared to designing circuits for matrix board, cutting unwanted traces, soldering things in place.

Comment: -1 for copping an attitude with @MarcusMüller, plus closing as "unclear" since despite all of the words, you really haven't told us much at all about your actual requirements. What kind of accuracy do you need for the settings? What kind of resolution? Since you're considering digital solutions, you can accept some jitter in the output -- how much is permissible? And so on ... If you had told us something about the application for this signal, we might be able to infer some of these specifications, but you've left us completely in the dark.

Comment: Furthermore, you seem to have some size constraints on the overall solution, yet you refuse to use SMD technology and/or commercial PCB fabrication. You're really turning this into an uphill battle. What do you expect from a bunch of volunteers?

Comment: LTC6992 springs to mind.

Answer (score 5):

Very clearly, this is a case for the PWM unit of a sufficiently fast MCU, as you noted.

Now, your whole counting of instructions is superfluous – MCUs come with PWM timers that do that job for you, and the CPU core is not involved in that. Thus, in some CPUs, PWMs can run at a much higher rate than the CPU core without problem.

So, yes, this is absolutely doable with the MCUs you mention. And also with MCUs that are a lot cheaper.

Personally, I like the PWM units on ST Micro STM32 arms. But that's really just because they're so easy to use; not because they are cheap. At the time of writing this, Silabs ARMs are cheap, so [if you've got 75ct per piece to spare and would like to write C for a 24 MHz 32 bit platform](http://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Silicon-Labs/EFM32ZG108F8-QFN24/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMuoKKEcg8mMKBN3KfvXoKGCf5cDMSHepAg%3d), why not?

If you need to go cheaper, really simply look into the cheapest microcontrollers that you can buy that come with a sufficiently flexible PWM unit. Really, PWM is such a common requirement that *most* microcontrollers have hardware for that, and you really don't need to have the CPU execute code to toggle an output with the right duty cycle and frequency.

Comment: It's a while since I've looked into this. How low can you adjust the PWM cycle time on one of those? 1 Hz?

Comment: @Transistor that really depends. Now, the MCU I linked to has a 16 bit PWM unit, so sysclk*2^-16, I guess? Others come with 32 bit counters. Now, you can often adjust sysclk in wide ranges, but I think the minimum for the linked IC generated from an *internal* clock generator (you can of course use a 555 to drive the MCU with a 42 Hz clock, if you really desire) is 1.2 MHz. Now, 1.2e6 / 2**16 would be something like 18 Hz? But really, if you need the lowest PWM frequencies, having 32 bit PWMs would sound wiser.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you. That kind of price would be quite acceptable. However, I notice this is an SMD chip. At present, I would prefer to stick to DIP, ideally DIP8. Can you suggest any DIP8 chip with a sufficiently configurable PWM capability?

Comment: @SodAlmighty If you want to stay ARM: [DIP is always pretty expensive](http://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/NXP/LPC810M021FN8FP/?qs=cbprxTG2Yq%2fZWYQ2Vx854A%3d%3d). If you don't care: Maybe a [MSP430](http://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/MSP430F2001IN/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsrb0xF%2fYczN4YS1ebc34vem7RyPD3ylNw%3d)? Or, really: just go ahead and buy an ARM dev board for <10€ for prototyping, and use SMD as soon as you go into series. Assembly cost of Through Hole is much higher than that of SMD, so if cost of your system is a relevant factor, DIP is usually out of question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I actually prefer Atmel chips. Or PICs. I've not had much luck with ARM.

Comment: @SodAlmighty well, then use ATSAM or Atmegas, but then I don't get your "cheapest and easiest possible" argument

Comment: You asked me if I wanted to "stay ARM". I do not. I have no desire to use ARM over anything else. All I'm wanting is a cheap small non-SMD solution, which essentially means DIP8.

Comment: Would a PIC12F683 be configurable enough for my requirements? I don't understand the datasheet sufficiently to know if it's good enough.

Comment: has a PWM module. might work! [Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41211D_.pdf) p. 77ff, as well as the application note referenced there.

Comment: The use of Timers to create a PWM is good, but the challenge is to produce PWM at high frequencies. In all probability to cover the range from 1Hz to 1 MHz you will need to use software PWM, Timer PWM, Double speed USART and potentially SPI. This would make the Atmel ATMega328 a good target processor

Comment: You're saying you want a DIP8 solution but you were considering two 555s and a 4017? Cheapest and smallest are often incompatible criteria.

Comment: "might work" is not a helpful response.

Comment: @Finbarr I was considering two 555s or a 555 and a 4017 because I didn't *have* a DIP8 solution. If I had a DIP8 solution I wouldn't have bothered writing this question. Are you *trying* to be argumentative, or is it a natural talent?

Comment: @SodAlmighty but "might work" is all I can give you. It's your product, I can't do the design for you, build and test it, just that you can get a definite "yes" or "no" for a MCU I've never used. You've got quite high demands!

Comment: Surely the datasheet, when read by someone who understands it sufficiently, would be enough to say for certain whether the chip does or does not support my requirements. If I understood PWM and datasheets better, I could check this for myself. But I do not. I'm not asking you to build the damn thing. I'm asking if it ought to have the necessary range and precision. I don't think that's too much to ask.

Comment: @JackCreasey That all sounds WAY too complicated. I barely understand the concept of PWM, let alone USART and SPI. I'm familiar with the 328, but not enough.

Comment: @SodAlmighty I wish datasheets were that almighty. I've got the better half of a problem and boundary conditions description from you, and I've never worked with the MCU you've mentioned, so I've never wrote software that works with the registers the MCU offers so I never learned to deal with the real-world problems that this particular piece of hardware might have. Worse even: the MCU datasheet is 200something pages long, and you expect me to read it for you? Sure, happening, as soon as you pay my hourly rates.Also,the datasheet says nothing about how good a developer you are,so "might work".

Comment: @MarcusMüller And of course, you'd have to read the *entire 200 pages* to figure it out, naturally. Look, if you don't know the answer, and aren't prepared to find out the answer, then why even bother responding? Enjoy wasting my time, do you? I asked for a solution. I didn't ask for "might work". If you can't help me, please go away.

Comment: @SodAlmighty Ok, you're being unfriendly, although I spend a lot of time explaining why my answer is "might work". I honestly don't know before I read all the pages on the PWM unit, on the timer, on the clock control unit, and on latencies. That's not surprising, that's how it is. **You** came here asking for help, I wrote an extensive answer, and now you're telling me to go away? Ok, someone's being a bit entitled today. Have a nice day.

Comment: You wrote an extensive *response*. That is not the same as an answer. I'm still no closer to solving the problem than I was to begin with.

Comment: @SodAlmighty I don't think that is my fault. That might completely be your inexperience, and also, your attitude. I showed up *several* ways to tackle your problem, but you just complained. Well, so be it. I tried to help you.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm just shocked at the way this discussion went sour. Your recommendations were solid and well-intentioned. And the OP just responds by accusing you of enjoying the process of wasting their time?!?? The OP appears to not want to work, at all, but wants others to just drop everything and provide a completely detailed solution together with any after-answer support needs. If I had had *any* prior interest in responding, that's certainly all gone now.

Comment: @SodAlmighty You wrote, *"I'm still no closer to solving the problem than I was to begin with."* You would be, if you were willing to work for your ***own*** solutions, rather than expect others to do so. You wrote, *"That all sounds WAY too complicated. I barely understand the concept of PWM.."* As Marcus said, you know the details of your problems better than anyone else. If you are too ignorant to be able to bridge the gap between where you are and where you need to be, that is no one else's fault but your own. And no one else but you has *any* responsibility to fix your ignorance problems.

Comment: Thanks, @jonk. I still hope SodAlmighty comes closer to a working system based on Jack's  and my approaches, so I think I'll leave it at this. Your comment has certainly improved my mood a lot :)

Comment: I'm glad I read the OP's comments before I submitted an analog solution. With that attitude I'm gone.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I also have similar hopes for SodAlmighty's success with this. And I'm glad that it helped your mood. I'm just chalking this up to his "waking up on the wrong side of the bed," today after also "biting off more than he can chew." (Um zwei englische Idiome zu benutzen, hoffe ich für dich OK.)